# Running a middleware script after successful login

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, is there a way I can trigger some scripts in middleware only after a successful login? I have tried using terminate function, "Before & After Middleware" but I got barrage of errors as the middleware triggers before login and my script depends on login parameters. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: after login means for authenticated users , why don't you add the middleware to routes which you have auth middleware for

Comment: I also thought of that but that will mean i will have to assign it to each route created,.Or can i create a constructor in web.php to trigger the middleware. Will it work?

Comment: you can assign it group of routes, not just one by one

Comment: That works like magic, i just moved my middleware declaration from "protected $middleware" to  "protected $middlewareGroups" under "web" and it works for me. Thanks Mahdi Younesi